# Indentation error in Python 2.7

Tags: python, comments, indentation

I'm getting an indentation error in this line of code (it's a comment with all spaces, no tabs), hope you can help me with this :)

```
import os
import socket
import connection
from constants import *
    """
    get_file_listing lists the files in the directory.
    """ # geting IndentationError: unexpected indent at this line's 5th column
    def get_file_listing(connection,):
        files = os.listdir(connection.directory)
        answer = str(CODE_OK) + " " + error_messages[CODE_OK] + EOL
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(connection.directory, f)
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                answer += f + EOL
        answer += EOL
        return answer
```

Comment: You'll have to identify the line of code that is giving you the error. Also edit the question to include the full error message

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Why did you indent the `def`? You don't need to indent after finishing your imports. The parser doesn't expect an indent there, so if you provide one it will not be able to compile your code.

Comment: Your docstring should be *inside* the function definition, not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 indentation errors. 
First one is your comment between """ """ tags. It is normal string so it has to match indentation rules. Use # instead.
Second one is line where you define your function. It needs to match indentation before.

```
import os
import socket
import connection
from constants import *
"""
get_file_listing lists the files in the directory.
""" # geting IndentationError: unexpected indent at this line's 5th column
def get_file_listing(connection,):
    files = os.listdir(connection.directory)
    answer = str(CODE_OK) + " " + error_messages[CODE_OK] + EOL
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(connection.directory, f)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            answer += f + EOL
    answer += EOL
    return answer
```